# How to pass raw Ansible params to Windows cmd without any encoding/decoding?

Tags: windows, ansible, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to set permissions to some windows directory like this

```
# ansible example.com -m raw -a 'icacls D:\somedir\ /grant "! ЗАО. Руководство":F' -vvvvv
```

and get windows error about invalid parameters

```
No config file found; using defaults
Loaded callback minimal of type stdout, v2.0
File lookup using /etc/ansible/host_files/example.com/mvs as file
<example.com> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: mvs on PORT 5985 TO example.com
<example.com> WINRM CONNECT: transport=plaintext endpoint=http://example.com:5985/wsman

<example.com> EXEC icacls D:\somedir\ /grant "! .  C:>2>4AB2>" :F

<example.com> WINRM EXEC 'PowerShell' ['-NoProfile', '-NonInteractive', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-EncodedCommand', 'aQBjAGEAYwBsAHMAIABEADoAXAAxAGMAXAAgAC8AZwByAGEAbgB0ACAAIgAhACAAFwQQBB4ELgAgACAEQwQ6BD4EMgQ+BDQEQQRCBDIEPgQiACAAOgBGAA==']
<example.com> WINRM RESULT u'<Response code 1, out "", err "Invalid parameter "!">'
example.com | FAILED | rc=1 >>
Invalid parameter "! ���. �㪮����⢮"
```

I see 2 problems:

1. Strange encoding or decoding of cyrillic parameter "! ЗАО.
   Руководство" (this is a group name in the windows) that passing from
   Ansible to windows host.
2. Adding extra space beetwen group name and permission

   "encoded bla-bla-bla": F

instead of

```
"encoded bla-bla-bla":F
```

How to fix it?

Ansible using from source (checked out at 17 August 2015)

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.0.0 (devel 4068598c15) last updated 2015/08/17 23:09:54 (GMT +600)
  lib/ansible/modules/core: (detached HEAD dea5f5d15e) last updated 2015/08/17 23:10:13 (GMT +600)
  lib/ansible/modules/extras: (detached HEAD 210ee3febc) last updated 2015/08/17 23:10:35 (GMT +600)
  v1/ansible/modules/core: (detached HEAD f8d8af17cd) last updated 2015/08/17 23:10:53 (GMT +600)
  v1/ansible/modules/extras: (detached HEAD 495ad450e5) last updated 2015/08/17 23:11:11 (GMT +600)
  config file =
  configured module search path = None
```

and running on Gentoo Linux

```
# uname -a
Linux web 3.10.4-gentoo #1 SMP Sat Aug 3 02:25:18 NOVT 2013 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

On other side - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard in KVM (on vultr.com)

Comment: Does this occur if you put the icacls command in a play book rather than on the command line?

Comment: A hint to solution: you have met some particular [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case.
Unicode codepoints for `. Руководство` are `002E 0020 0420 0443 043A 043E 0432 043E 0434 0441 0442 0432 043E` and those for `.  C:>2>4AB2>` are `002E 0020 0020 0043 003A 003E 0032 003E 0034 0041 0042 0032 003E` i.e. all higher bytes were set to `00`. Unicode codepoints for `! ЗАО.` are `0021 0020 0417 0410 041E 002E` and that's why this string is shortened to `! .` i.e. only printable characters from `0021 0020 0017 0010 001E 002E`. Strings from `<example.com> EXEC` log.